# css3 first-child in anchor of list items

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<style type="text/css">
#featured a:first-child
{
 background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<div id="featured">
   <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
     <li><a href="#"><span>test 1</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>test 2</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>test 3</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>test 4</span></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I wanted to highlight first anchor from the list, but unfortunately all anchors are highlighted. What is the mistake do here.

Comment: you want to highlight the link which is clicked , is it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are all highlighted because each `a` is the first-child of its parent `li`

What you probably want is something like:

```
#featured li:first-child a
{
 background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Working solution, but targeting anchor tags inside lists only. The original attempt from the OP did not. But I think it is what he wants and therefore a +1 for you. :-)

Comment: That's what the OP said, "I wanted to highlight first anchor from the list"

Answer (score 2):

Because all anchors are the first child of their parents. You need to:

```
#featured li:first-child a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always have a list I would prefer the CSS solution like @powerbuoy and @danwellman posted. If you just want to format the first anchor tag nested inside an arbitrary tag (with id `featured`) with arbitrary nesting-level then I would prefer jQuery:

```
$('#featured a').first().css('background-color', 'yellow');
```

Example with div's rather than an unordered list: http://jsfiddle.net/9vAZJ/ 
Same jQuery code formatting a list (like in the question): http://jsfiddle.net/9vAZJ/1/

The jQuery code is a more general solution and fits better to your initial try to format the anchor tag in your question since both solutions are **decoupled from list tags**.

Nevertheless when list-styling is your only task here then I would recommend the CSS solution.